# Eclipse GWT plugin - Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, compilation, compiler-errors

I am using the Google Web Toolkit plugin for eclipse and I cannot compile my projects to run outside of development mode. I am getting a popup message and it is printing a message to the console, but I cannot figure out how to solve this issue.

The message that I get in a popup says:

```
'GWT Tutorial - GWT Compile' has encountered a problem.
GWT compilation failed
```

(The name of my project is GWT Tutorial)

The console message is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler
```

If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by outside of the project ? do you mean right click on the project and compile using Eclipse GWT plugin or Command line ?

Comment: @LakshithaRanasingha I meant outside of developer mode and I am using the Eclipse GWT plugin.

Comment: I have same issue but in my case gwt-dev-2.1.0.jar corrupted. replace this jar as per your version then check.

Comment: @Bhumika How would I just get the .jar file for this?

Comment: @Bhumika Never mind I got it to work by downloading the separate version than moving the gwt-dev.jar file from the new downloaded version into the plugin location. This worked. Thanks.